# How to check whether one file's value contains in another text file? (perl script)

Tags: perl

I would like to check one of the file's values contains on another file. if one of the value contains it will show there is existing bin for that specific, if no, it will show there is no existing bin limit. the problem is I am not sure how to check all values at once.

first DID1 text file value contain :

```
L84A:D:O:M:
L84C:B:E:D:
```

second DID text file value contain :

```
L84A:B:E:Q:X:F:i:M:Y:
L84C:B:E:Q:X:F:i:M:Y:
L83A:B:E:Q:X:F:i:M:Y:
```

if first 4words value are match, need to check all value for that line. 
for example L84A in first text file & second text file value has M . it should print out there is an existing M bin

below is my code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename  = 'DID.txt';
my $filename1 = 'DID1.txt';
my $count     = 0;
open( FILE2, "<$filename1" )
  or die("Could not open log file. $!\n");
while (<FILE2>) {
    my ($number) = $_;
    chomp($number);
    my @values1 = split( ':', $number );
    open( FILE, "<$filename" )
      or die("Could not open log file. $!\n");
    while (<FILE>) {
        my ($line) = $_;
        chomp($line);
        my @values = split( ':', $line );

        foreach my $val (@values) {
            if ( $val =~ /$values1[0]/ ) {
                $count++;
                if ( $values[$count] =~ /$values1[$count]/ ) {
                    print
                      "Yes ,There is an existing bin & DID\n @values1\n";
                }
                else {
                    print "No, There is an existing bin & DID\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot check all value. please help to give any advice on it since this is my first time learning for perl language. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm afraid we're going to have a hard time really understanding your question, as you talk about bins and bin limits without any context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding I write this code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
#use ReadWrite;
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

use vars qw($my1file $myfile1cnt $my2file $myfile2cnt @output);

$my1file = "did1.txt";  $my2file = "did2.txt";
```

We are going to read both first and second files (`DID1` and `DID2`).

```
readFileinString($my1file, \$myfile1cnt); readFileinString($my2file, \$myfile2cnt);
```

In first file, as per the OP's request the first four characters should be matched with second file and then if they matched we need to check rest of the characters in the first file with the second one.

```
while($myfile1cnt=~m/^((\w){4})\:([^\n]+)$/mig)
{
    print "<LineStart>";
    my $lineChk = $1; my $full_Line = $3; #print ": $full_Line\n";
    my @First_values = split /\:/, $full_Line; #print join "\n", @First_values;
```

If the first four digit matched then,

```
    if($myfile2cnt=~m/^$lineChk\:([^\n]+)$/m)
    {
```

Storing the rest of the content in the same and to be split with colon and getting the characters to be matched with first file contents.

```
        my $FullLine = $1;  my @second_values = split /:/, $FullLine;
```

Then search each letter first and second content which matched line...

```
        foreach my $sngletter(@First_values)
        {
```

If the letters are matched with first and second file its going to be printed.

```
            if( grep {$_ eq "$sngletter"} @second_values)
            {
                print "Matched: $sngletter\t";
            }
        }
    }
    else {  print "Not Matched...";  }
```

This is just information that the line end.

```
    print "<LineEnd>\n"
}

#------------------>Reading a file
sub readFileinString
#------------------>
{
    my $File = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    use File::Basename;
    my $filenames = basename($File);

    open(FILE1, "<$File") or die "\nFailed Reading File: [$File]\n\tReason: $!";
    read(FILE1, $$string, -s $File, 0);
    close(FILE1);
}
```

Comment: I think we're definitely going to need some more explanation of what this code is doing.

Comment: sure champ I will do

Comment: thank you ssr1012 , when i tried to run the code , i got below error Can't locate ReadWrite.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/MTApps/perl/5.12.2/x64/prod/site/lib C:/MTApps/perl/5.12.2/x64/prod/lib .) at test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 3.

Comment: i tried to install the cpan beach , but it failed to install 
LWP failed with code[500] message[LWP::Protocol::MyFTP: Bad hostname 'mirror.its.uidaho.edu']
Fetching with Net::FTP:

Comment: I have commented my own module `ReadWrite`. It won't be problem if you have commented.

Comment: why you are installing `cpan beach`

Comment: oh ok. i would like to check with you one thing , if user edit the first file DID1 text file by switching the first row and second row to L84C:B:E:D: L84A:D:O:M: would it the output still showing match value is B E for L84C and M for L84A ?

Comment: Yes It will shows if the four digits matched on second file content then it will shows the matched content

Answer (score 0):

Read search pattern and data into hash (first field is a key), then go through data and select only field included into pattern for this key.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $input1 = 'DID1.txt';                      # look for key,pattern(array)
my $input2 = 'DID.txt';                       # data - key,elements(array)

my $pattern;
my $data;
my %result;

$pattern    = file2hash($input1);             # read pattern into hash
$data       = file2hash($input2);             # read data into hash

while( my($k,$v) = each %{$data} ) {          # walk through data
    next unless defined $pattern->{$k};       # skip those which is not in pattern hash
    my $find = join '|', @{ $pattern->{$k} }; # form search pattern for grep
    my @found = grep {/$find/} @{ $v };       # extract only those of interest
    $result{$k} = \@found;                    # store in result hash
}

while( my($k,$v) = each %result ) {           # walk through result hash 
    say "$k has " . join ':', @{ $v };        # output final result
}

sub file2hash {
    my $filename = shift;
    my %hash;
    my $fh;

    open $fh, '<', $filename
        or die "Couldn't open $filename";

    while(<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        next if /^\s*$/;                      # skip empty lines
        my($key,@data) = split ':';
        $hash{$key} = \@data;
    }

    close $fh;

    return \%hash;
}
```

Output

```
L84C has B:E
L84A has M
```

Comment: thanks alot! i have tried it out this code but i am getting below error 

Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at new1.pl line 37, <$fh> line 4.

Comment: @PannPhyuPhway -- my guess is that you may have an empty lines which is read and key/data can not extract from such line. In a moment I will add one more line into the code which should skip empty lines.

Comment: @PannPhyuPhway -- please see the line in subroutine with the comment. Try to run the code once more.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried out the code. there is no error getting anymore. but the output only show one line. it doesn't show second line match letter .                                                                       
L84C has B:E
L84A has